# Will I have to resort to for loops for comparing two 2d arrays in C++?

Tags: c++

I have two 3x3 arrays that are filled with float numbers.  My objective is to get the difference of each corresponding cell and compare it to a set value.  `custSmiles` just helps me determine if all the cell differences is below `custSmiles`.

So far, I have

```
double shopperChoice = 0.80;
int custSmiles = 0;
for(int a = 0; a < 4; a++) {
    for(int b = 0; b < 4; b++) {
        if((wheat[a][b] - nineGrain[a][b]) < shopperChoice) {
            custSmiles++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so where is the question? Sorry

Comment: Is there a function that I can use so that I won't have to use for loops?

Comment: Why it is a < 4 and b < 4 in a loop condition?

Comment: If its just 4 iterations on each list, go with what you have if it works as intended.

Comment: The arrays are both 3x3.  Edit: If I am faced with 2d arrays that are 50x50, then this method starts to drag things down.

Comment: Will the max length of your arrays change? If its a very small length you could hard code the compares (YUCK) - but even at 4x4 that would be 16 individual compares (YUCK^2). What is it about iterating through loops that is an issue?

Comment: @RikoKurahashi If the matrix is 3x3, then you're looping out of bounds.

Comment: Also, there are [standard algorithms](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) the *encapsulates* the loops, but there's no way to avoid them.

Comment: Loops or recursion are ur only way to go

Comment: Never seen a programmer not to love loops. They save time and a**es on a daily basis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Will I have to resort to for loops for comparing two 2d arrays in C++?`

It's late, i'm really bored and i made this, take it as you will however i felt this had some kind of worth, if i made any mistakes someone should feel free to tell me, so i stop doing whatever it is that i shouldn't be doing, i'm only trying to help and i certainly don't do things wrong knowingly..

Also I realize i pick some god awful names but you can change them to whatever you want, i'm working on choosing better names, if you find anything useful in this, slice it up and make it work for you, anyway enough rambling.

**main.cpp**;

```
#include <iostream>
#include "hide.h"

int main(){

    float array_A[3][3] = {
        {1, 1, 1},
        {1, 1, 1},
        {1, 1, 1}
    };  
    float array_B[3][3] = {
        {0.1, 0.2, 0.3},
        {0.4, 0.5, 0.6},
        {0.7, 0.8, 0.9}
    };

    hide::setChoice(0.35);

    hide A(array_A), B(array_B);

    std::cout<< "\ncounter after A - B: "<< A - B << "\n";

    hide::resetCounter();
}

    /* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
     *
     * the values returned by ( A - B ) are useless in this
     * context it would only make sense if you changed this
     * to fill/populate them with the proper values.
     *
     * that said this version of the class evaluates the
     * the same expression you did in the if statement within
     * the for loops (x[a][b] - y[a][b] < c) on each element
     * within the array/s.
     *
     * This effectively *hides* the for loops if you don't
     * look in the classes source files when you're thinking
     * "Geez i hate loops".
     *
     * lastly there is no bounds checking (or error) present,
     * you can index any value you could without a class
     * wrapped around the array should you decide to do that.
     *
     * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
     *
     * (A - B) evaluates to s_counter
     *                  
     *  A (or) B.access( row, col ) treats like 2d
     *
     *  A (or) B.index( i ) treats like 1d
     *
     *  access() & index() are not used in the example
     *
     * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
     *
     * hide::getCounter() also returns s_counter
     *
     * hide::resetCounter() sets s_counter to 0
     *
     */
```

---

**hide.h**

```
#ifndef HIDE_H
#define HIDE_H // include guard

// width and height constants need to be set accordingly
#define _WIDTH 3
#define _HEIGHT 3

class hide {
    private:
        static const int s_height;
        static const int s_width;
        static float s_choice; // a.k.a shopperChoice
        static int s_counter; // a.k.a custSmiles


        float (*m_array)[_WIDTH];
        /*
         * I'm using this as a pointer to
         * a multidimensional array, that is what
         * a 2d array really is under the hood,
         * i prefer to just use it that way and
         * create the abstractions myself..
         */

    public:
        static float setChoice(const float &choice);
        static int resetCounter();
        static int getCounter();

        hide(float (*ptr)[_WIDTH]);
        ~hide();

        float access(const int &row, const int &col);
        float index(const int &i);

        int operator-(hide &aHide);
};

#endif
```

---

**hide.cpp**

```
#include "hide.h"

// static initializations
int hide::s_counter = 0;
float hide::s_choice = 0;
const int hide::s_height = _HEIGHT;
const int hide::s_width = _WIDTH;
//------------------------------------

// Constructor
hide::hide(float (*ptr)[_WIDTH]){
    m_array = ptr;
}

// Destructor........
hide::~hide(){
    // default
}

// overloaded (-) minus operator to perform the
// desired operation, this could be changed to
// any operator you feel better suited..
int hide::operator-(hide &aHide){

    for(int i = 0; i<s_height*s_width; ++i){
        if( (*m_array)[i] - aHide.index(i) < s_choice ) {
            ++s_counter;
        }
    }
    return s_counter;

}

// static member functions
//----------------------------
// resets s_counter to 0
int hide::resetCounter(){
    s_counter = 0;
}

// sets choice to a specified value
float hide::setChoice(const float &choice){
    s_choice = choice;
}

// returns s_counters current value
int hide::getCounter(){
    return s_counter;
}
//----------------------------

// access m_array like a 2d array
float hide::access(const int &row, const int &col){
        return (*m_array) [row*s_width+col];
}

// access m_array like a 1d array
float hide::index(const int &i){
    return (*m_array) [i];
}
```

---

[ORIGINAL ANSWER] You can resort to just one *for loop* with a pointer to an array of arrays;

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    const unsigned height = 3, width = 3;

    float A[height][width] = {
        {1, 1, 1},
        {1, 1, 1},
        {1, 1, 1}
    };  
    float B[height][width] = {
        {0.1, 0.2, 0.3},
        {0.4, 0.5, 0.6},
        {0.7, 0.8, 0.9}
    };

    int counter = 0;
    float choice = 0.35;

    for(int i = 0; i < height*width; ++i){
        if( (*A)[i] - (*B)[i] < choice ) {
            ++counter;
        }
    }

    std::cout<< "counter: " << counter; 
}
```

output;

```
counter: 3
```

Comment: This will work, maybe. But remember that code will be far more often be read than wrote. And as a reader I think "what is happening here"?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. When it comes to arrays, vectors, matrices or stuff like this and you want to do the same operation (comparing, for example) on each (or on a subset) of the cells then loops are the weapon of choice.

It doesn't matter if you choose for- or while-loops (or other more uncommon constructs).

Sidenote: What matters though is readability. But fortunately, if you do it right, loops will support this. Personally I'm inclined to extract inner loops to separate functions. If the function name is chosen well, this helps a lot. Like Joachim Pileborg already stated, encapsulation is the key here.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your code describes what you have to do, that is, compare the difference from each corresponding cell in a pair of matrices, then yes, you will need to "visit" each cell, and this requires some form of loop. So there is no way to avoid that.

As others have said, if your matrix is 3x3, then you should have `a < 3` and `b < 3`, or you go outside the matrix in your loop.

There are possibly ways that you could write it in a different way, but I can't really think of any that makes is "nicer" in this case.

If your goal is to determine if ALL cells are below a certain value, then you can "stop early" if the value doesn't match your criteria. Something like this:

```
success = true;
for(int a = 0; a < 3 && success; a++)
{
   for(int b = 0; b < 3 && success; b++)
   {
      if((wheat[a][b] - nineGrain[a][b]) >= shopperChoice) {
         sucess = false;
      }
   }
}
```

And then instead of `if (custSmiles == 9)` or whatever, you do `if (success)` to determine that it was a "good one".

It probably makes little difference in this case, but will save substantial time for very large matrices that often "don't match" [assuming the mismatch is venly distributed position, if it's always the lower right corner, then you may want to do the loop in reverse, or some such].